# How to ensure that a statement gets executed after a loop completes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

Below is a snapshot  of my code from routes/index.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var results=new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<1000;i++){
        //do database query or time intensive task here based on i 
        // add each result to the results array
    }
    res.render('index', { title: 'Home !' , results:results });
};
```

If I run this code , due to the asynchronous nature of javascript the last line gets executed before the loop gets completely processed . Hence my webpage doesnt have the results . How do I structure this such a way that the page gets loaded once the queries are completed ?

---

### Updated

Inside the loop I have database code ( Redis ) like the below -

```
client.hgetall("game:" +i, function(err, reply) {

           results.push(reply.name);
        });
```

Comment: What exactly is in the loop body? Does it support callbacks?

Comment: hi zerkms - I just updated the question to add details about that part as well . Yes it supports callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  var events = require("events");
  var e = new events.EventEmitter();
  e.expected = 1000;
  e.finished = 0;
  e.results = [];

  e.on("finishedQuery", (function(err, r) {
    this.finished += 1;
    this.results.push(r && r.name);
    if (this.finished === this.expected) {
       res.render('index', { title: 'Home !' , results:this.results });
    };
  }).bind(e));

  for (var i = 0; i < e.expected; i++) {
    client.hgetall("game:" + i, function(err, reply) {
      e.emit("finishedQuery", err, reply);
    });
  };
};
```

Of course, the above code doesn't handle [1 or more] errors. You'd need to add logic that only responds (1) on the first error or (2) if no errors occur.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var results=new Array();
    async.forEach(someArray, function(item, callback){
        // call this callback when any asynchronous processing is done and
        // this iteration of the loop can be considered complete
        callback();
    // function to run after loop has completed
    }, function(err) {
        if ( !err) res.render('index', { title: 'Home !' , results:results });
    });
};
```

If one of the tasks inside the loop is asynchronous, you need to pass the asynchronous task a callback that calls `callback()`. If you don't have an array to use in `forEach`, just populate one with integers 1-1000.

*Edit*: Given your latest code, just put the `async` `callback()` right after `responses.push(reply.name)`.

Comment: I don't see how your second version is better than OP's original.  The first one is good, but make sure `callback` gets called after result is added to the results array, not just at the end of the loop body.

Comment: Yes, see edited answer about passing i increment into callback.

Comment: See my note about incrementing i and doing the conditional check via a callback *after* any async processing.

Comment: In your second example, some of the items will run multiple times.  A non-asynchronous for loop isn't going to work.