# Web scraping: close to 15% end up as partial downloads when using Mikeal's request module for node.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I'm scraping an inspiration gallery and downloading the images to disk using Mikeal's `request` library for node.js. The problem is that a bunch of images, mostly at the start of the download session, end up downloading partially or not all. This is shown in the image below (folder sorted by `Date Modified`). After the first 17 images, the rest download fine as you can see starting from row 3, column 4.

[image: Partial downloads]

Here's the relevant segment of the node.js/request code I'm using:

```
// images is an array of URLs to .jpg images
for( var i = 0, len = images.length ; i < len ; i++ ) {
    request.get( images[i] ).pipe( fs.createWriteStream(destinationFilename) )
}
```

I'm using `request` to fetch the image data from the URLs stored in the `images` array and pipe it to a `stream` that writes it to disk. Most of the time this works fine but somewhere between 1 to 15% of the downloads end up being partial downloads.

I tried using the `drain` event of the `stream` object to get the `bytesWritten` and compare it with the `bytesTotal` but that approach didn't get me anywhere. Are there other approaches to solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [async](https://npmjs.org/package/async). You must use async.queue and send requests with finite parallelism. What your code is doing is trying to spawn of `images.length` number of requests simultaneously. Node.js is non-I/O blocking. So you need some control over number of events you spawn off. Async is the packagae you need.

Comment: Didn't have time to experiment with `async` but I could confirm that it was indeed the saturation of requests that was the problem by batching them up into chunks of 10 requests at a time with `setInterval`. Worked without a hitch. Will try the `async` and `event emitter` approaches later when I find time.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your entire script, I'd guess that your process is terminating before all of your requests have finished. You might try, as previously suggested, the async library, but you can accomplish this faster by taking full advantage of asynchronous requests with an [event  emitter solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907495/how-to-ensure-that-a-statement-gets-executed-after-a-loop-completes/13920464).

Hope this helps!