# In node.js, how do I make a asynchronous callback in this situation

Tags: node.js, callback, mongoose

Firstly, I have a array of data in json, for example, 
var a = [{'name':'jack','age':15},{'name':'tom','age':30}];

And what is more, I have a mongodb based database, which is implemented in mongoose. Inside the database, there is a user collection storing user's other information.

So right now, I want to query the information in a list of people shown above.

```
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    console.log('time schedule '+"   "+a[i].name+"   "+a[i].age);                               
    model.findOther(a[i].name,function(err,data){ 
        // I can get the data from mongodb  
          console.log("time schedule data:"+"   "+data.otherinfo+"  ");
       --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       //however the problem arises that I can not get the a[i].age inside the callback
          console.log(a[i].age );

    });                                             
}
```

I know it is kind of wrong to get the right data, so could anyone help me how to write the code in asynchronous way?

Comment: Take a look at async. npm install async https://github.com/caolan/async#each

Comment: Thanks Hector, async works, but I have a additional requirement that the results should have the same sequence with original array. async.forEach doesn't work in that way, I have also tried async.eachSeries, but the code is never excuted, strange to me

Comment: I recommend checking out my answer to a similar query at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907495/how-to-ensure-that-a-statement-gets-executed-after-a-loop-completes/13920464#13920464

Comment: `async.forEachSeries` is a natural fit here; update your post with what you tried that didn't work as it takes a bit to 'get' how that library works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your function into a closure and push the related variable as a parameter into it:

```
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    console.log('time schedule '+"   "+a[i].name+"   "+ai].age);
    (function(item){
        model.findOther(item.name,function(err,data){ // <-- here you could use 'a[i]' instead of 'item' also
            console.log("time schedule data:"+"   "+data.otherinfo+"  ");
            console.log(item.age );  // <-- here you must use 'item'
        });
    }(a[i])); // <-- this is the parameter of the closure
}
```

Comment: One of @user824624's comments mentioned that he needs the results to be in the same order as the original array. That might be easier if you also passed in the index, e.g. `(function(item,index){ ... })(a[i],i)`

Comment: You are right concerning his comment, and it might work. But he only gets the same sequence if the callbacks come in the same sequence. That might be the normal behavior, but there is no guarantee an that. But, o.k., your index can show him the order. So it is better anyway ;-)